# What is permission required to use OpenRemoteBaseKey?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I had asked about this in some other thread and got the link to access remote registry. But the problem I am now facing is I am not able to add any values in to registry. I was trying to add some values to an existing entry in a registry by using following code but not doing anything in remote registry:

```
RegistryKey rk;
rk = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(
RegistryHive.CurrentUser, ReadServerName());
regkey = rk.OpenSubKey(LeafRegistry.LeafRoot + "\\sim\\NewView\\");
regkey.SetValue("runsystem", SIMserver);
```

**UPDATE**

RegistryHive.LocalMachine will work here, I can open and do all operation, but then why for RegistryHive.CurrentUser ? What I am saying is in the above code I will get value for 'rk' but I cannot get value for regkey which will become null, I think for CurrentUser OpenSubKey is not working.

**UPDATE**

When I analyzed in depth, I saw for except this particular key, all other keys are accessible. I am wondering what is going on for this specific key, I checked permission also after right clicking, but couldn't see it?

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly require permissions in most cases when you are attempting to change registry values on remote machines across a network. Also, in a lot of cases, even where you can amend the registry values they can be refreshed via Group Policies and reverted back.

It could be that there are certain parts of the registry that you are restricted from editing,

If you don't have administrator privelages then I think you will come unstuck.

Comment: i have admin privileges , i added my userid to the Administrators group in remote system

Comment: RegistryHive.LocalMachine will work here, i can open and do all operation ,but then why for RegistryHive.CurrentUser  not working?

Comment: What i am saying is in the above code given in question i will get value for 'rk' but i cannot get value for regkey which will become null , i think for currentsuer OpenSubKey is not working

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work. Suppose the user account your program is accessing remote machine under is not logged in on the remote machine. What should Windows do? Actually, documentation for [`RegConnectRegistry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724840.aspx), which is what `OpenRemoteBaseKey` calls internally, does not even list `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as a permissible argument.

Comment: i have admin privileges , i added my userid to the Administrators group in remote system

Comment: It is irrelevant. Despite what MSDN says about OpenRemoteBaseKey, it isn't possible to open HKEY_CURRENT_USER remotely, see link above on RegConnectRegistry. You could try opening HKEY_USERS/(your user's SID), but this will work only if your user is already logged in on the remote machine. RegConnectRegistry will not load the user's hive for you. You may need to rethink your approach.

Comment: What i am saying is in the above code given in question i will get value for 'rk' but i cannot get value for regkey which will become null , i think for currentsuer OpenSubKey is not working

Comment: Hm. Again, is your user logged on to the remote machine? Check with regedit whether the user's hive is loaded into HKEY_USERS there. If not, you are probably getting a readonly default user key. In any case, why are you doing it this way? Maybe you can use group policy or something?